# DataKey names in Form view

Tags: asp.net

How to access dataKey values

```
 <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server"  Style="margin-right: 65px"
   DataKeyNames="MMBProfileID"
<ItemTemplate>
        <table id="FormViewTable" style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Name:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Eval("MMB_Name") %>
                </td>
```

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MMBProfileId = Convert.ToInt32(FormView1.DataKey["MMBProfileID"]);
 FormView1.DataSource = objBLL.Execute_ViewBusinessProfile(MMBProfileId);
```

}
This is giving me an error. 
Input string not in correct format at (FormView1.DataKey["MMBProfileID"]);

Any hints will be appreciated
Thanks
Sun

Comment: What value is FormView1.DataKey["MMBProfileID"]?  Check that it's an integer...

Answer (score 1):

I would say FormView1.DataKey["MMBProfileID"] can't be converted to an integer.